# Design pattern to (de)serialize data from

Tags: xml, json, design-patterns, json.net, yaml

Suppose I have some data in a file in XML, JSON or YAML formats. All documents have the same logical structure. In simple case:  all files have in root element attribute Version.

I suppose to create class that can read and write data from/to file this formats:

```
 enum FileFormat {JSON, XML, YAML};

 class File {
    FileFormat FileFormat { get; } // We cannot change file format
    int Version { get; set; } // We can read/change root attribute Version 
    Load(string fileName, FileFormat fileFormat); // We can load from JSON/XML/YAML formats
    Save (string fileName); // We can save changed  in the same format as we read
}
```

Which design pattern should I use in Load/Save to choose the right serializer/deserializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the textbook scenario for the [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).